# How to delete duplicate rows from table if they are written in a minute period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with the following data:

```
TriggerId  TableName     EmployerCode   CreatedDate               UserInfo     OperationName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   9       Employeers    834320         2020-08-06 16:05:13.427   GRP\Office1  Update
  10       Employeers    834320         2020-08-06 16:05:13.480   GRP\Office1  Update
  11       Employeers    834320         2020-08-06 16:07:13.480   GRP\Office1  Update
```

I need to "clean" the table removing duplicate rows written in a specific period of time (one minute).

The duplication is defined by four columns:

```
TableName, EmployerCode, UserInfo, OperationName
```

So in the example only line 10 has to be removed because it is a duplicate of line 9.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four columns which define the duplicates are: TableName, EmployerCode, UserInfo, OperationName.  Something like this

```
delete t
from tTest t
where exists (select 1
              from tTest t2
              where t2.EmployerCode = t.EmployerCode and
                    t2.TableName = t.TableName and
                    t2.UserInfo=t.UserInfo and 
                    t2.OperationName=t.OperationName and
                    t2.CreatedDate >= dateadd(minute, -1, t.CreatedDate) and
                    t2.CreatedDate < t.CreatedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.employercode = t.employercode and
                        t2.tablename = t.tablename and
                        t2.createddate >= t.createddate - interval '1 minute' and
                        t2.createddate < t.createddate
                 );
```

Note that date/time function vary among databases, so you might need to adjust the syntax for your database.

Also, this specifically answers the question that you asked. But if a given row is duplicated every 30 seconds, then only the first row will be kept - regardless of the total duration.